# Sort DBGrid by clicking column's title

Tags: delphi, sorting, dbgrid

Well, this seems a little tricky (if not imposible). I'm trying to make my DBGrid sort its data by clicking on column's title.

The thing is that I'm (sadly) working with Delphi 3, I'm not using ADO DataSets and the query gets a lot of rows, thus I can't reopen my TQuery changing the `order by` clause on clicks.

Someone has implemented something like this?

Answer (score 9):

This is actually done by sorting the dataset, and then the grid reflects the change.  It can be done easily enough by creating an index on the dataset field for that column.  Of course, this can only be done on a dataset that supports index sorting, such as `TClientDataset`.

Comment: As stated, the orde of a DBGrid is based on the order of the data in the TDataset. So the only way to change the order of the DBGrid is to change the order of the TDataset, which depends on the actual TDataset descendant you are using... So you might considder creating you own TDataset descendant which reflects the data of another TDataset in the desired order.

Comment: `TFDQuery` also supports index.

Answer (score 4):

On the TDBGrid's OnTitleClick method you can do something like...

```
procedure TfmForm1.DBGrid1TitleClick(Column: TColumn);
var
   i: Integer;
begin
   // apply grid formatting changes here e.g. title styling
   with DBGrid1 do
      for i := 0 to Columns.Count - 1 do
         Columns[i].Title.Font.Style := Columns[i].Title.Font.Style - [fsBold];
   Column.Title.Font.Style := Column.Title.Font.Style + [fsBold];

   with nxQuery1 do // the DBGrid's query component (a [NexusDB] TnxQuery)
   begin
      DisableControls;
      if Active then Close;
      for i := 0 to SQL.Count - 1 do
         if (Pos('order by', LowerCase(SQL[i])) > 0) then
            //NOTE: ' desc' The [space] is important
            if (Pos(' desc',LowerCase(SQL[i])) > 0) then 
               SQL[i] := newOrderBySQL
            else
               SQL[i] := newOrderBySQL +' desc';
      // re-add params here if necessary
      if not Active then Open;
      EnableControls;
   end;
end;
```

There are plenty of ways in which you could optimise this I'm sure however it depends on the capabilities of the components you use. The example above uses a query component though if you used a table component you'd change the index used instead of the 'order by' clause.

The handling of the SQL here is a very basic version. It does not handle things like SQL batch statements, resulting in possible multiple 'order by..' clauses or commented SQL statements i.e. ignoring bracketed comments "{..}" or single line comments "//"

Regards

Comment: The question specifically says "hus I can't reopen my TQuery changing the order by clause on clicks.". How does posting an answer that  does exactly what the question asks **how not to do** help?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a combination of `TFDQuery`, `TDataSource` and `TDBGrid` you can order with this easy way!

```
procedure TFrmGer.DBGridTitleClick(Column: TColumn);
begin
  OrderByTitle(MyFDQuery, Column);
end;
```

Put it in a helper file so you can use it latter again.

```
procedure OrderByTitle(AQuery: TFDQuery; Column: TColumn);
begin
  AQuery.IndexFieldNames := Column.DisplayName;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Delphi 3 have `TClientDataset`. And `TQuery` can use explicitly created indexes on the database to order data on the `IndexName` property.

Comment: Not necessarily true, neither my Delphi 4 Pro nor my Delphi 5 Pro installation have TClientDataSet. Maybe it's only in the Enterprise version?

Comment: Hmmm. On these versions I only touched Enterprise editions (since I normally worked in loco). But D3 Enterprise certainly have TClientDataset.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples of how to do this: [Sorting records in Delphi DBGrid by Clicking on Column Title](http://delphi.about.com/od/usedbvcl/l/aa042203a.htm) .

As already mentioned, sorting is quite easy if you are using a `TClientDataSet` (`cds.IndexFieldNames := Column.FieldName` in the `OnTitleClick` of the `TDBGrid`). However if you are not able to do this you can either regenerate your query (which you have stated you don't want to do) or obtain a more advanced data grid such as [Express Quantum Grid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExQuantumGrid/) (which I think allows you to sort).

Answer (score 0):

On the TDBGrid's OnTitleClick method you can write this simple code:

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid3TitleClick(Column: TColumn);
var
  cFieldName:string;
begin
  cFieldName:= DBGrid3.SelectedField.FieldName;
  AdoDataset1.Sort:=cFieldName;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

example: (https://www.thoughtco.com/sort-records-in-delphi-dbgrid-4077301)

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
var
 pt: TGridcoord;
begin
 pt:= DBGrid1.MouseCoord(x, y);
 if pt.y=0 then
 DBGrid1.Cursor:=crHandPoint
 else
 DBGrid1.Cursor:=crDefault;
end;

procedure TForm1.DBGrid1TitleClick(Column: TColumn);
var
  cFieldName:string;
begin
  Adotable1.Sort := Column.Field.FieldName;
end;
```

Comment: please explain how this answers the question

Answer (score 0):

Ascending and Descending Mode

```
  if Pos('DESC',PChar(Q2.Sort))>0 then
    Q2.Sort:=Column.FieldName  + ' ASC'
  else
    Q2.Sort:=Column.FieldName  + ' DESC';
```